# Menu_Opciones() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'Pregunta' and 'Opciones'

Tags: python, django, parameters, arguments, view

I have a problem which evolve a script: "script.py" and a view in "views.py" in a django project.
The goal is to show in a page a question: "Pregunta" and a list of options: "Opciones" 
In a part of the script I need to call a view's function "Menu_Opciones" in this way:

```
ESI_App.views.Menu_Opciones(request, Pregunta, Opciones)
```

In views.py I have the function defined in this way:

```
def Menu_Opciones(request, Pregunta, Opciones):
    for i in range(len(Opciones)):
    ModelOpciones.objects.create(opciones=Opciones[i])
    form = OpcionesForm(request.POST or None, field1_qs = ModelOpciones.objects.all())
    context = {
    'pregunta': Pregunta,
    'form': form,
    }
    if form.is_valid():
        opcion = form.cleaned_data['Campo_Opciones']
    return render(request, "Menu_op.html", context)
```

Here's the traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/Menu_Opciones/

Django Version: 1.9.7
Python Version: 3.4.3
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'ESI_App']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Users\Miguel\Desktop\VenvProyecto\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\Miguel\Desktop\VenvProyecto\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

Exception Type: TypeError at /Menu_Opciones/
Exception Value: Menu_Opciones() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'Pregunta' and 'Opciones'
```

**More information:** I have this error since I changed computer but I created a new proyect and app, copied the code, modified all paths, project files and folder names, app name, settings... carefully.

As you can see, I call the function with that 3 arguments and I can't imagine why get that error. Please, give me a hand.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I call the function with that 3 arguments." Are you sure? It looks like you're simply calling `http://127.0.0.1:8000/Menu_Opciones/`. I don't see anything in that URL that could be passed to your view.

Comment: Hello @nofinator , Menu_Opciones() is a "views.py" function which have 2 arguments: "Pregunta" and "Opciones" and I call this view from the script in this way: ESI_App.views.Menu_Opciones(request, Pregunta, Opciones) I'm sorry, I didn't understand your answer

Comment: That call from your script looks correct since it has 2 arguments after request. However, in your traceback above, it looks like Django is responding to a URL call that you made, which doesn't appear to have anything after `/Menu_Opciones/`. How are you running your script?

Comment: I explain you the program flow: **1º** I show a form in the index page, (urlpattern: `url(r'^$', 'ESI_App.views.inicio', name='inicio'),`) (`view: def inicio(request):`) **2º** I get a text variable through request.POST method. **3º** Inside the view's function, I call the main function in "script.py" : (`solution = main(request, text_variable)`) **4º** Inside the main function, I call the view in this way: `ESI_App.views.Menu_Opciones(request, Pregunta, Opciones)` and ask the wiew's function: (`def Menu_Opciones(request, Pregunta, Opciones):`) to show the menu in Menu_Op.html

Comment: ...I continue: (urlpattern = `url(r'^Menu_Opciones/$', 'ESI_App.views.Menu_Opciones', name='Menu_Opciones'),`).  Then my intention is redirect automatically from 'inicio' to 'Menu_Opciones', get an option selected through request.POST and process it and show the final answer, but I will try to get next on my own. Thanks @nofinator for the answer, I hope I explained it enough clearly :)

Comment: Oh, I see. Your script is supposed to be making a POST call. But in the Traceback above, it looks like a GET. Maybe that is the problem?

Comment: The "request" flow is: **1º** (view:) `def inicio(request):` **2º** (inside that view:) `solution = main(request, text_variable)` (view --> script) , **3º**  (script:) `ESI_App.views.Menu_Opciones(request, Pregunta, Opciones)` (script --> new view).   I humbly think that in the traceback the request appear as GET by default, because the program stops before I use that request as POST. What do you think, @nofinator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it! First I tried to pass the parameters as keyword but got the same error, so I tried simply to define in views "Pregunta" and "Opciones" as global variables:

```
Preg = ''
Opcs = []
```

I imported them in "script.py" and asigned their proper value:

```
ESI_App.views.Preg = Pregunta
ESI_App.views.Opcs = Opciones
```

Then, I call the view and use those global variables :)
I know it's not elegant abusing of global variables, but it avoided the error and solved the problem.
If you find another elegant solucion or way to solve that error, I would appreciate it and would mark his solution as accepted.